# Reveal mouse pointer position

Tags: gnome, accessibility, mouse-pointer

On Windows it is possible to enable revealing the mouse pointer position by pressing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.

Is this possible in Gnome? There doesn't seem to be a setting, unless it's hidden somewhere.

Comment: @muru Good catch. I was looking for that a few days ago.

Answer (score 8):

I don't expect this to win "best answer", but there's always the old "xeyes" method.

Placing one at each top corner even lets you triangulate the position.

[image: two sets of animated eyes looking at the cursor]

Comment: Funny and functional!  **:-) +1**

Comment: I like this little gadget. I see you have 929 points so +1 on your journey to 1000.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is hidden in the CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) Accessibility settings.

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

and then:

- Open `CCSM`
- Navigate to <kbd>Accessibility</kbd>
- Click the checkbox before <kbd>Show mouse</kbd>
- Click on <kbd>Show mouse</kbd>
- Click on the first button after <kbd>Initiate</kbd>
- Press a ***key combination!***
  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> by itself will not work: I have it set to  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>: the "Windows key" + "K")
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
- Now press the key combination you just took

#### and it'll show you a flaming whirlwind of stars around your cursor impossible to miss:

[image]

## :-)

Comment: Used to use that on Unity 16.04 , one of my favorite Compiz features

Comment: Although this might be a good solution, installing Compiz only to enable this feature is overkill. Compiz was installed with Unity but not with Gnome AFAIK. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This no longer works for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Snowcrash I'm still on 16.04 so better [Ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and post a link to this answer that this does not work any more and let some with 18.04 answer.

Comment: Upvoting and hoping you will vote to reopen :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Open again...

Comment: That is great but... Our friend @muru is back at full stride and his keen eye found a real duplicate which I could not...