# Ubuntu: mouse sonar

Tags: mouse-pointer

Is there a way of creating a sonar effect to find your mouse cursor on Ubuntu 18.04?

Ideally something that can be triggered via a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reveal mouse pointer position](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143974/reveal-mouse-pointer-position)

Comment: @Fabby that answer is for Unity not Gnome.

Comment: Typical Ubuntu desktop rubbish - something this simple was done on Windows years ago and it's still not easy on Ubuntu.

Comment: Show me a Windows screenshot with [a flaming whirlwind of stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I19GC.png) as shown in [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143974/reveal-mouse-pointer-position) that is not really a duplicate... @Snowcrash  **0:-)**

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://github.com/arp242/find-cursor) shows a mouse 'sonar' effect, in lieu of the 'mouse trail' effect typically used in Ubuntu, using an xlib program courtesy of [arp242](https://github.com/arp242) which you must make and compile. It can be mapped to a specific key.

Comment: I'm not make'ing, compiling and binding keys to get something like this working. Can you imagine if you had to do that on the Mac!

Comment: I am sure Hiro Protagonist could help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 19.10 
- use gnome-tweaks (sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool)
- select Keyboard & Mouse
- In Mouse section, select pointer location

pressing ctrl will show the mouse location when this option is activated!

Comment: Installed and doesn't work.